# Need help in removing duplicates

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT date,
id,
CASE WHEN app_info like '%purchase%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as purchase_ind,
CASE WHEN app_info like '%cancel%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as cancel_ind,
CASE WHEN app_info is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as total_ind,
CASE WHEN app_info  like '%refund%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as refund_ind
FROM db_name.schema_nm.tbl_name
WHERE date = '2022-24-01'
AND flag_column = '0'
AND source_cd NOT IN ('1','2','3','4');
```

When I run the above query, I'm getting results but there are duplicate records.
What is the way to eliminate the duplicate records? Kindly help.

I'm getting results like this:

```
ROW   DATE        ID      purchase_ind  cancel_ind  total_ind  

1    2022-24-01  01234     0              0         0          
2    2022-24-01  01234     0              0         0
```

Comment: I don't see a duplicate row here. total_ind is different, that means there are at least 2 rows, and one of them has app_info is NULL, and the other one has app_info without not-null but not-matching row. What do you want to see?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I'm getting duplicate records like the one which you could see now..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to avoid duplicate records by date and id, so you could take your query into a CTE expression and then just MAX over all indicators:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
DISTINCT date,
id,
CASE WHEN app_info like '%purchase%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as purchase_ind,
CASE WHEN app_info like '%cancel%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as cancel_ind,
CASE WHEN app_info is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as total_ind,
CASE WHEN app_info  like '%refund%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as refund_ind
FROM db_name.schema_nm.tbl_name
WHERE date = '2022-24-01'
AND flag_column = '0'
AND source_cd NOT IN ('1','2','3','4')
)
SELECT date, id, MAX(purchase_ind) AS purchase_ind, MAX(cancel_ind) AS cancel_ind, MAX(total_ind) AS total_ind, MAX(refund_ind) AS refund_ind
FROM CTE
GROUP BY date, id;
```

Comment: @Jenifer I really don't understand, you said you don't see any difference in the output rows, in this case, this query should return 2 rows again.

Answer (score 0):

The original query has the DISTINCT keyword, and Jenifer claims both rows are the same. If the DISTINCT query produces 2 identical rows (which is impossible unless you hit a bug), you can't reduce it to one using GROUP BY. Let me show how I repro the issue and why GROUP BY can't help:

```
create or replace table dummy (date VARCHAR, id VARCHAR, app_info VARCHAR  )
as
SELECT * from VALUES 
('2022-24-01','01234', NULL ),
('2022-24-01','01234 ', NULL)
;

SELECT 
DISTINCT date,
id,
CASE WHEN app_info like '%purchase%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as purchase_ind,
CASE WHEN app_info like '%cancel%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as cancel_ind,
CASE WHEN app_info is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as total_ind,
CASE WHEN app_info  like '%refund%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as refund_ind
from dummy;
-- returns 2 rows

WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
DISTINCT date,
id,
CASE WHEN app_info like '%purchase%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as purchase_ind,
CASE WHEN app_info like '%cancel%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as cancel_ind,
CASE WHEN app_info is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as total_ind,
CASE WHEN app_info  like '%refund%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as refund_ind
FROM dummy
)
SELECT date, id, MAX(purchase_ind) AS purchase_ind, MAX(cancel_ind) AS cancel_ind, MAX(total_ind) AS total_ind, MAX(refund_ind) AS refund_ind
FROM CTE
GROUP BY date, id;
-- returns 2 rows
```

I don't have access to data, but IMO, the issue should be related to the ID or DATE column. We don't know their type, but an extra space character could be the issue. So, in this case, **TRIM** may help:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT TRIM(date),
TRIM(id),
CASE WHEN app_info like '%purchase%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as purchase_ind,
CASE WHEN app_info like '%cancel%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as cancel_ind,
CASE WHEN app_info is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as total_ind,
CASE WHEN app_info  like '%refund%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as refund_ind
from dummy;
-- returns 1 row
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I will check and get back.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of issue I like row_number() over partition. Before applying "r_number=1" you can check all the rows and see which ones you are going to keep. It can be useful to track the origin of duplicates.

```
SELECT 
    date,
    id,
    CASE WHEN app_info like '%purchase%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as purchase_ind,
    CASE WHEN app_info like '%cancel%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as cancel_ind,
    CASE WHEN app_info is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as total_ind,
    CASE WHEN app_info  like '%refund%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as refund_ind
FROM (
    SELECT 
        date
        ,id
        ,app_info
        ,row_number()  OVER (PARTITION BY date, id) AS r_number
    FROM db_name.schema_nm.tbl_name
    WHERE date = '2022-24-01'
        AND flag_column = '0'
        AND source_cd NOT IN ('1','2','3','4')
) tbl_name
WHERE r_number=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the SQL you note is giving you duplicates, your strings must be non-equal. to detect this, covert each of them to BASE64 or adding extra tokens.

```
WITH fake_data(date, id, app_info, flag_column, source_cd) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        ('2022-24-01', '1', 'good id', '0', 9),
        ('2022-24-01', ' 1', 'space before id', '0', 9),
        ('2022-24-01', '1 ', 'space after id', '0', 9)
)
SELECT debug_inner_sql.*,     
    'X'||debug_inner_sql.id||'X' as check1,
    BASE64_ENCODE(debug_inner_sql.id::text) as check2
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        date,
        id,
        IFF(app_info like '%purchase%', 1 ,0) as purchase_ind,
        IFF(app_info like '%cancel%', 1 ,0) as cancel_ind,
        IFF(app_info is not null, 1 ,0) as total_ind,
        IFF(app_info like '%refund%', 1 ,0) as refund_ind
    FROM fake_data
    WHERE date = '2022-24-01'
        AND flag_column = '0'
        AND source_cd NOT IN ('1','2','3','4')
) as debug_inner_sql
```

gives:

| DATE | ID | PURCHASE_IND | CANCEL_IND | TOTAL_IND | REFUND_IND | CHECK1 | CHECK2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-24-01 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | X1X | MQ== |
| 2022-24-01 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | X 1X | IDE= |
| 2022-24-01 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | X1 X | MSA= |

So we can see that once the data is formatted in HTML you cannot see the `ID` column values are all different, where this can be seen in CHECK1 and CHECK2 allows, pulling the EXACT values out and into something like notepad++ to see what is in the data. There could be some unicode tokens in your data, etc etc.

I assume date is a actual DATE, but given there is a string test, that is not your problem.

Once you know what column is inconsistent, you start applying data clear via [TRIM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/trim.html) or the likes.